Angular 16 using FontAwesome icons in TinyMCE v7
I've been through a lot of TinyMCE documentation, previous questions and various other online resources but I just can't figure out how to get FontAwesome icons to show in a TinyMCE editor without using the deprecated CDN and unicode references.
My setup is:

Angular v16
TinyMCE v7 self hosted i.e. installed @tinymce/tinymce-angular and added the assets and scripts copy to angular.json
FontAwesome Pro license with the @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons as well as all the other font libraries installed.
Setup FontAwesome addIconPacks in app.module.ts
My TinyMCE editor is configured like this in my component:

<editor
  [(ngModel)]="html"
  [init]="{
    promotion: false,
    entity_encoding: 'raw',
    license_key: 'gpl',
    extended_valid_elements: '+span[*],+i[*],fa-icon[*]',
    base_url: '/tinymce',
    suffix: '.min',
    plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount'
  }"
></editor>

I have tried loading the following HTML in the control:
<i class="fal fa-alarm-clock"></i>
<fa-icon [icon]="['fal', 'circle-x']"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon [icon]="['fal', 'alarm-clock']"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon icon="circle-x"></fa-icon>

None of the above icons are shown BUT the HTML is in the control correctly i.e. it was not removed or replaced with other HTML tags.
FYI, all of the above do display correctly in the component if used outside of the TinyMCE editor.
However, it is worth noting I have been able to get an icon to display IF I use the now deprecated CDN and add the font family 'FontAwesome 6 Pro' to TinyMCE and use unicode characters like this:
<i class='fas'>&#xf780;</i>


The above isn't really a good option because the CDN is being deprecated and ideally I want people to be able to easy change to a different FontAwesome icon!
Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.
